# Is it possible to use the .NET Podio API to send emails from Podio the way Globiflow is able to?

Tags: c#, .net, api, email, podio

I know that Globiflow has the ability to allow users to send emails from Podio. We would like to convert this to our custom backend instead of using Globiflow. Which brings up our question: is it possible to use Podio's API to send emails from Podio? I'm not seeing any documentation for this so any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible. The reason you aren't seeing any documentation on that for Podio is because the Podio API is only for getting data out of Podio or editing data that is already in Podio. You can use any of the SDKs from Podio to get the data out, but then you need to send the email with a tool of your choice. This can be custom coded in a programming language and hosting environment of your choice, but I recommend integrating with Mailgun using their API: https://www.mailgun.com/

Hope that helps!